# generic action method mvc with database call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am searching for a way to make generic action methods that can be inherited by multiple controllers, so I don't have to repeat the same method in MVC for different controllers and tables. I think this would be applicable to a lot of the CRUD stuff I have to frequently do for multiple classes.

For example, here's the code I'd like to duplicate:

```
public ActionResult ToggleQC(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        BACTERIA_EVW bacteria = db.BACTERIA_EVW.Find(id);
        if (bacteria == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        //add/remove QC status (switch to whichever one it isn't right now)
        if (bacteria.QCOn == null) //if it hasn't been QCed
        {
            bacteria.QCOn = DateTime.Now;
            bacteria.QCBy = User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else //if it has been QCed and they are undoing it
        {
            bacteria.QCBy = null;
            bacteria.QCOn = null;
        }
        //save changes
        db.Entry(bacteria).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        //return updated QC status partial
        return PartialView("_QCStatus", bacteria);
    }
```

I need to do the same thing in a chemistry controller, but I'd rather not repeat the whole thing and just change one part. Is it possible to pass the model type into the method as a parameter, to replace `BACTERIA_EVW`? How would I do that?

I apologize if this is something really basic; I may not know the right terms to look for. I've searched for generic action methods but I haven't found any answers, although there was something about generic controllers - do I need to make a generic controller class somehow to include a method like this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What you probably need is a generic method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx call it from your controllers

Comment: google "abstract methods"

Comment: @Shekhar Need to be way more than just "read on generics" to deal with "db. *BACTERIA_EVW* .Find" or saving updates...

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about removing `code redundancy` you can create a `generic controller` with that method and inherit other controllers from that:

```
 namespace BaseControllers
 {
     public class CoolController
     {
         public virtual ViewResult Get() 
         {
             var awesomeModel = new object();
             return View(awesomeModel);
         }
     }
 }
```

And in your child controller:

```
 public class CoolController : BaseControllers.CoolController
 {
     public override ViewResult Get() 
     {
         var ignoredResult = base.Get();
         // ViewData.Model now refers to awesomeModel
         return View("NotGet");
     }
 }
```

Same can happen for other `CRUD` operations.

Comment: Hi Yaser, how do I deal with the database call in the child controller? Does it "know" that the awesomemodel is referring to the model I'm using in the child class?

Comment: I thought you wanted to reuse db code as well, if they have different db code what would be the point of having that parent controller. If you care about the code reuse, I suggest going towards using a repository pattern with generics to avoid any duplication of code, all the db code can be handled in base class then